# SpringBoot Application Test Cases Error with IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I am trying to integrate the test case in my spring boot application and for that I  have added these configs in my `build.gradle`

```
plugins : {
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.10" 

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco")
    }
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.java.coveragePlugin', 'jacoco'
    }
}
```

Now After that, I have created a test folder in a similar way and wrote my Test Controller.

This is my actual class:  `ErrorController`

```
package com.company.app.controllers; 

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/error")
@Log4j2
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({@Autowired}))
public class ErrorController {
  @GetMapping
  public String index(Model model) {
    return "404";
  }
}
```

This is my test class: `ErrorControllerTest`

```
package com.company.app.controllers;

@WebMvcTest(controllers = ErrorController.class)

public class ErrorControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/error"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("404"));
    }
}
```

Things are loading fine as I can see in report. Now when I am running this I am getting error like

But this the error I am getting.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'callbacksController' defined in file [/Users/david/Git/app/build/classes/java/main/com/company/app/controllers/CallbacksController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionService' defined in file [/Users/david/Git/app/build/classes/java/main/com/company/app/services/SpringSessionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.company.app.repositories.SpringSessionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:132)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionService' defined in file [/Users/david/Git/app/build/classes/java/main/com/company/app/services/SpringSessionService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.company.app.repositories.SpringSessionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 104 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.company.app.repositories.SpringSessionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1357)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 118 more


ErrorControllerTest > testIndex() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException at DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1801
1 test completed, 1 failed
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///Users/david/Git/app/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 16s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Can you please suggetst me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: can you share SpringSessionRepository and SpringSessionService and CallbacksController ?

Answer (score 1):

Main error of the test class you are running is showing error in application context  that  is not able to load try to add package name before class name it will fix the error  i guess.

Comment: can you show me with example what is needed here with my code

Answer (score 1):

This line in error log

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.company.app.repositories.SpringSessionRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Says that `SpringSessionRepository` bean was not injected into Spring context during test

Comment: what should I do to resolve. I have just tried with one of the controller.

Comment: @David you should share full code, so it will be possible to find the issue

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.app")` annotation. It is scanning every class in `com.company.app` package and its subpackages and failing when attempting to initialize the `SpringSessionService`(which is needed for the `CallbacksController` bean), due to a missing `SpringSessionRepository` bean. If you want to test the `ErrorController` class with a complete application context that includes all beans, you should use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead of the `@WebMvcTest` annotation. On the other hand, if you are fine with the minimal application context that `@WebMvcTest` provides, remove the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.app")` annotation as the test needs only the `ErrorController` bean, which will already be initialized by `@WebMvcTest(controllers = ErrorController.class)` and because the `ErrorController` bean doesn't need any other beans/dependencies.

Comment: Even after removing `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.app")` and having only `@WebMvcTest(controllers = ErrorController.class)` I am getting the same error.

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be happening. I did try this out with the exact same `ErrorController` and `ErrorControllerTest` in the question and with another test controller that was missing a bean. The test worked fine when only the `@WebMvcTest(controllers = ErrorController.class)` annotation was present. And the test failed when I added the `@ComponentScan` annotation which would have scanned the other controller as well. Is the complete ErrorController whatever is already present in the question?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the `@WebMvcTest` java docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) :

> `value` / `controllers` - Specifies the controllers to test. May be left blank if all
> `@Controller` beans should be added to the application context.

Meaning, `ErrorController` is automatically included in the application context via `@WebMvcTest(controllers = ErrorController.class)`. Thus, you should remove the `@ComponentScan` annotation, since it adds unnecessary components to the application context.

Furthermore, the errors appear because these unnecessary components have dependencies on repositories usually enabled by [`@EnableJpaRepositories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html). Since the test is related to `ErrorController`, other components are irrelevant to the test.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a SpringBoot application, you should be using @SpringBootTest to load the application context.

```java
package com.company.app.controllers;

@SpringBootTest(SpringBootApplication.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = ErrorController.class)
public class ErrorControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    protected void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/error"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("404"));
    }
}
```